# What determines receiving a gathering profession quest?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Gathering potency is heavily influenced by your skill at gathering a particular material from a particular source. This skill is increased by quests, which start from items you get while gathering . However, I have not been able to determine a pattern to receiving these quests. What determines how you receive these quests?

Answer (score 6):

You get them by farming the appropriate items. Eventually a quest item will appear in the loot or the quest pops up directly depending on the recipe.

If you farm a certain material there is a chance to get the quest or quest item for the next rank's quest chain. *While it is pretty easy to obtain the quest for the first ranks, the higher ones are harder to get and it's pretty much random/rng and luck.* 
I have people in my guild farm all day long and still chasing rank 3, while others got it pretty early. (Just like almost everything in WoW. There's no pattern or "you get 10 ores, I give you a quest".)

<s>Some ranks may not yet be obtainable as the quest wants you to kill a raid boss</s>* (Felwort Rank 3 for example requires to kill Cenarius in the Emerald Nightmare)

If you want to see what's awaiting you, you can check all Legion profession quests on [WoWHead](http://www.wowhead.com/quests/professions?filter=35;7;0) (and/or filter them by single professions)

`*` Raids are open by now, so everything is obtainable.

Comment: Are you sure it's totally random with *nothing* else governing it? I find that hard to believe given how important it is for gathering potency.

Comment: @twobugs in Beta there was nothing else than that and with Legion being live for a week now it does look the same way. A few people in my guild have obtained the quest for rank 3 pretty soon (below 800, so this is not a factor) and a few still chase for them, although they farm A LOT. The only requirement is having the previous rank for that item. I can't back it up with numbers, but it really feels like random.